# For loop does not continue after while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I have a while loop inside a for loop. Individually they both work as expected but combined the for loop does not continue after the first iteration of the while loop.

I am stuck getting this to work as I can not figure out where my mistake is.

```
import ccxt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

exchange = ccxt.binance({ 'enableRateLimit': True })
now = int(round(datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())*1000))

data = []
symbols = ['ETH/USDT', 'BTC/USDT', 'LTC/USDT']
date = 1649196000000
for symbol in symbols:
    while date <= now:
        ohlcv = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, '1d', date, 20)
        data.append(ohlcv[0])
        # print symbol to check which symbol has been fetched
        print(symbol)
        # print date to view table
        print(data)
        # update date variable with date from last record
        date = data[-1][0]
        # increase date with one day to fetch new record
        date += 86400000
```

Output

```
ETH/USDT
[[1649203200000, 3407.0, 3407.5, 3162.39, 3168.51, 736273.1047]]
ETH/USDT
[[1649203200000, 3407.0, 3407.5, 3162.39, 3168.51, 736273.1047], [1649289600000, 3168.52, 3268.98, 3143.15, 3227.19, 458179.3272]]
ETH/USDT
[[1649203200000, 3407.0, 3407.5, 3162.39, 3168.51, 736273.1047], [1649289600000, 3168.52, 3268.98, 3143.15, 3227.19, 458179.3272], [1649376000000, 3227.2, 3314.02, 3173.52, 3192.39, 502422.5048]]
ETH/USDT
[[1649203200000, 3407.0, 3407.5, 3162.39, 3168.51, 736273.1047], [1649289600000, 3168.52, 3268.98, 3143.15, 3227.19, 458179.3272], [1649376000000, 3227.2, 3314.02, 3173.52, 3192.39, 502422.5048], [1649462400000, 3192.39, 3228.23, 3181.28, 3220.46, 110418.446]]
            date     open     high      low    close       volume
0  1649203200000  3407.00  3407.50  3162.39  3168.51  736273.1047
1  1649289600000  3168.52  3268.98  3143.15  3227.19  458179.3272
2  1649376000000  3227.20  3314.02  3173.52  3192.39  502422.5048
3  1649462400000  3192.39  3228.23  3181.28  3220.46  110418.4460
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe `date <= now` is not true anymore after the first iteration of the `for` loop? Use debugging techniques to find out!

Comment: That is something I still have to learn. I found your article 'how-to-debug-small-programs' and will read it. Thank you

Comment: It's not my article, but thanks.

Comment: Move the assignment to *date* inside the *for* loop

Answer (score 1):

The first `while` loop runs until `date > now`.

Then the next iteration of the `for` loop starts. The `while` loop is skipped because `date > now`.